# api request not working in React when i set a parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

im trying to put an input value as a parameter in the url of my request but it doesnt update when i change it, im using template strings and putting the state in {}, it doesnt show error in console.

```
function SerchProducts() {
const [products, setproducts] = useState()
const [input, setinput] = useState()
  
  useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get(`https://dfv-ecom.eu/api/v3.1/{input}`)
  .then(res => setproducts(res.data))
  
  },[])
  
  
  
  const handleSubmit = e =>{
  setinput(e.target.name-products.value)
  }

  const fetchcart = async () => {
    setcart(await commerce.cart.retrieve())
  }
  const handleaddtocart = async(productId,quantity) => {
  
     setcart( (await commerce.cart.add(productId,quantity)))
  }
  
  return (
  <div className="cont">
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <input id="name-product"> type="text"
  </input>
  <button>search</button>
  </form>
  </div>
  )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be that you're not setting your state input in the dependency array in your `useEffect` hook, this array works as an "observer", so every time there's a change in your state value it would make a new request.

Like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`https://dfv-ecom.eu/api/v3.1/${input}`)
    .then(res => setproducts(res.data))
}, [input])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the empty dependency array you've supplied, this effect should only execute once after the component's initial render:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get(`https://dfv-ecom.eu/api/v3.1/{input}`)
    .then(res => setproducts(res.data))
}, [])
```

And in that initial render, the value of `input` is `undefined`:

```
const [input, setinput] = useState()
```

> but it doesnt update when i change it

If the effect should execute again any time `input` changes, include it in the dependency array:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get(`https://dfv-ecom.eu/api/v3.1/{input}`)
    .then(res => setproducts(res.data))
}, [input])
```

---

**Edit:** Additionally, the syntax highlighting identifies a typo.  You're not using template strings properly (forgot the `$`):

```
useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get(`https://dfv-ecom.eu/api/v3.1/${input}`)
    .then(res => setproducts(res.data))
}, [input])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Campton,**

`useEffect` can be your best friend or your deadly enemy, be careful with that.

In your case, you need to search using a debounce. There are several ways to achieve that.

This will solve your problem but it will take you to a dark place with other problems like stale closure, cancel requests, etc.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://dfv-ecom.eu/api/v3.1/${input}`)
    .then(res => setproducts(res.data))  
  },[input])
```

I strongly recommend you take a look at this short video [React Hooks explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6P86uwfdR0&list=PLZlA0Gpn_vH8EtggFGERCwMY5u5hOjf-h) to get a better understanding of hooks in general before going deep in `useEffect`.

There is a nice library called [react-query](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-start-using-react-query-4869e3d5680d) that will save a lot of time when dealing with Rest API. Read this 2nd article and you will learn a lot.